# Is it ok to pass a ListView activity as (this) to a instantiated object ie ArrayAdapter?

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter

I have a listview `NoteList` which contains a method `doListRefresh()` to select list contents from the sqlite `note` table, populates a cursor (which populates my `array adapter`), then calls `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` to refresh the list. Upon (add, edit, deletes etc)

Inside my custom `Array adapter` i populate several elements on each row including a delete button. Inside the `array adapter` i have the delete button `onClick` handler etc. I need to call `NoteList.doListRefresh()` from within my `Array adapter` and i do this by using a setter inside my `array adapter` which is called from `NoteList` something like `adapter.setNoteListObj(this);`. This is working but i'm not sure its the best way?

I wanted to ask if this is "best practice" for doing something like this?

Thank you for any advice

Here is some of the sample code:

**Within NoteList:**

```
onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  thisObject = this;
}

// set custom ArrayAdapter to the data
adapter =  new NoteArrayAdapter(activity, R.layout.channel_note_list_item, noteList);
adapter.setNoteList(thisObject);
```

...

**within Adapter:**

```
private NoteList callingNoteListObj;

... 

// setter
protected void setNoteList(NoteList _callingNoteListObj) {
  this.callingNoteListObj = _callingNoteListObj;
}

...

// within delete onclick handler (after delete)
// refresh local database
callingNoteListObj.doListRefresh();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see why not. All you are doing is passing a reference to the instance (a "pointer" for those who have done more than Java). Personally, I'd pass `this` into the constructor for your adapter and store the reference locally. In fact, you probably already do if you pass in `this` as a Context object in order to construct an `ArrayAdapter`. Since its your custom adapter for your custom NoteList, you could very well just cast `context` (or `this.getContext()`) to NoteList and call it without needing to use a setter.

Comment: Interesting you say that about the context that sounds like a good idea however my arrayadapter constructor doesn't include context ie `NoteArrayAdapter(Activity _activity, int _layout, ArrayList<Note> _notes)`. So only includes Activity not Context. Or am i missing something?

Comment: actually Yeah i might change it around to pass the reference directly via the constructor rather than a setter. But yeah as i said above i don't think its already passed because i pass through the activity for a ArrayAdapter not a context.

Comment: Oh it's inside a ListView. I was thinking about my own app where I just used a ListActivity and the context/activity was the first parameter for the ListAdapter (similar to the ArrayAdapter) constructor. I suppose in your case you'd have to add the view as another parameter. But that's not too bad, right?